# NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"

Tags: ios, sockets, ftp, connection, wifi

I have a strange problem sending **more than one file** on FTP server **via WiFi network** in a specific environment. I use my own, self-made ftp client (made on sockets).

- When I test the transfer sending files on my server 'S1' in my environment 'E1' everything is ok.
- When I test the transfer sending files to server 'S2' in 'E1' everything is ok also.
- When a person is sending files to my server 'S1' in 'E2' everything is ok, too.
  But
- When a person is sending files to his server 'S2' in 'E2' the transfer is broken after sending one file (!) and the error appears:

  > Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be
  >   completed. Connection refused"

**UPDATE**: And one more important thing: The person can send the same files with success to 'S2' in 'E2' via other device (Nokia with Symbian).

I have really no idea what's going on. Do you?

```
'S1' - my ftp server in my location
'E1' - my environment: an iOS device, WiFi network W1, firewall F1,
'S2' - ftp server in other country
'E2' - environment in other country: an iOS device, WiFi network W2, firewall F2
```

Comment: Are the two devices both using passive mode?

Answer (score 1):

The posix network functions will not cause iOS to turn on the WiFi radio if it has gone to sleep.  You must use some NS-methods to make it wake and begin to connect.